# Is there an adapter for a Sigma SA mount lens to fit a Canon EF mount?

Tags: canon, lens-mount, sigma

I have a Sigma 24mm ultra-wide lens; does anyone know of an adaptor that will make this lens fit my Canon 1V camera?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is there is no adapter. An adapter would mean the lens would be further from the focal plane than normal, and you probably wouldn't be able to focus.

What people have done is to disassemble an old Sigma with an EF mount, and then swap the EF mount onto the SA lens - see the two posts below:

http://www.camerahacker.com/Forums/DisplayComments.php?file=Lens/converting_sigma_SA_mount_lenses_to_Canon_EF

http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/thread/2564329#forum-post-31536316

Answer (score 0):

This will never work, because the flange distance of the EF mount will not allow an adapter to fit in between the SA Mount lens and the EF mount. You can mount Olympus OM lenses to EOS EF for example, the mount adapter is just a couple of millimeters in size.

Sigma basically makes an EF Mount version of most of their SA lenses, you would have to go with that.